# Backing up data

Tags: macos, terminal, backup, script, automation

I have a script that used to run daily that looked like the following to backup my mac.

[Backup script pastebin](http://pastebin.com/RxHrb0Tm)

As you see here, this script is TERRIBLE because it deletes everything in the folder then pastes it all in. Also if you can't tell im trying to backup to google drive but the limit stops me from updating. I do own a apple timemachine but much rather having a copy in drive. any tips on fixing it?

Comment: How long does the script take? Are you looking to minimize the time to upload or for suggestions for a fuller featured tool like Arq? https://www.arqbackup.com If you describe in detail what a fix looks like, it's more likely someone will have a relevant idea.

Comment: The script takes about 30- 1 hr the first time run, then it should take less time but because its replacing everything it takes 1 hr every time, my goal is to simpily copy EVERYTHING (but ~/Google\ Drive) so it uploads to drive.

Comment: also, im looking for a free software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help with the Google Drive question. I can help with a better backup script. I do backups from local disk to local disk using a tool called rsync that comes installed on every Mac and can be accessed in Terminal or using a script like the one you have.

```
rsync --verbose --ignore-errors --archive --exclude '.*' --itemize-changes --delete --progress /Volumes/SourceDrive /Volumes/DestinationDrive
```

Have a look at rsync documentation for explanation of all the options I use. This command will compare your source and destination, copy over files that are not on the destination, remove files from your destination  that are not on the source anymore for whatever reason.

You can replace the source and destination above for any folder anywhere on your system, so it should work just fine for Google Drive too.

I configured cron jobs to have my backup run at night and send my phone a notification every time it completes, so it's all automated. My cloud backups run off the local backups, so they update daily rather than constant. That's a matter of preference I guess.

*Please note: This command has a clear source and destination, it is not a syncing in two directions. There is no way to undo what it does, deletions are final and not to the Trash.*

Comment: I do use cron to do it every night at midnight

Comment: also, how do  you make it copy EVERYTHING but one folder (like in my case, ~/Google\ Drive)

Comment: Copy everything except one folder? You add another --exclude 'Google\ Drive' option to the command. In that case it will copy everything from the source to the destination, except that folder.